# How to declare custom type correctly with predefined acceptable values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I have this type declaration:

```js
declare const csvSeparator: unique symbol;
export declare type CSVSeparator = ';' | ',' | ' ' | '|' | '.' | '\t'
  & { readonly [csvSeparator]: 'CSVSeparator' };
```

Then I try to define this structure:

```js
const predefinedColumnSeparators: ColumnSeparatorInterface[] = [
  {name: 'Semicolon', character: ';'},
  {name: 'Comma', character: ','},
  {name: 'Space', character: ' '},
  {name: 'Pipe', character: '|'},
  {name: 'Colon', character: '.'},
  {name: 'Tabulator', character: '\t'},
];
```

But in here I get an error `Type '"\t"' is not assignable to type 'CSVSeparator'`.

How can I declare my custom type correctly? Or is there any better way to define acceptable values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made `'\t'` in `CSVSeparator` a [nominal string type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) (also called branded primitive). The error in the assignment occurs, because a regular `'\t'` string cannot be assigned to this nominal `'\t'` anymore. Also the nominal typing (the intersection part) is only applied to `'\t'`:

```
type CSVSeparator = ... | ... | ('\t'  & { readonly [csvSeparator]: 'CSVSeparator' })`
// read like this:              ^                                                   ^
```

I think, you have two options here: 1. use regular strings (the simple one) or 2. branded strings (stronger types).

**1. Simple string** ([Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAYQGUA1Y4MTdGaOAXjgHIBuJuAH2YBp2v2%20zDoKYA6EQB0YTALAAoecggA7AM7wwWJADMAlsuAJCEVAFcAtsopUoNaKoBccAN5xl6c8Cfqo%20gOYscMgAFtTIMMBQTiTklNS0UHAAvgDaALpwDHAp8pnO7p5OTBTmukqoKkzcQaG24ZFFbEncuS4FXszG5uboVTVhEVE8TM2t%20R4dxVTIwH0hAw3MzKNyee1FAAq6BHO16PVDTMIraxNFxhXKuwuH4idtZ8wAKugARqYYCdd1g0VSIy05GkWEA))

```
export type CSVSeparator = ';' | ',' | ' ' | '|' | '.' | '\t'

const predefinedColumnSeparators: { name: string; character: CSVSeparator }[]  = [
  {name: 'Semicolon', character: ';'},
  ...
  {name: 'Tabulator', character: '\t'},
];
```

**2. Branded string** ([Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0WgbgZRAAdYoMkYAueAVxQEsBHahNATwFsAjJCAbgFgAUEIytCCAEIwoKUMAA8AFXggAHhhCy08TDDooA5gD54AXnjKAZPADe8OFGCoIreAG0wuAsWlkYAXSoAcgBhPAA1bxI-IPgAXyEhADNaMAw6VHhOaVklFXVNYG1dfWMACjQqRQBKWyF4BvsQDGoYFB14KG0pGTklIyEE4UE1QnIsUXF4MMiiaPIzesaAH3ge2RAFIN4ggcFG+FX1vqCAGl2lhqOck-gL-ZW1m835IOX7g+vel6CAOg-HscfgAdDD3ITIdBYQhwUBJfSbEI8ajsFBRXzkSq2eAoKDsEBUEqGXiIAAWJDSIEo0wi6NICzibn8Zncl2xuPxwQI7DoyAgqDOZIpGmp2V6ZW2QVqcVObLsHIJd25vJ4AtOQuklOpkvi6oA9HqVDAYJj1SgkE0DNRoDAdBg9IZOmg0HQDLjOBAEHKcXjFaEkOx2FBBWByZqRVQxbIJedpbKHg15b6ucQwCAQ2GoFrIzcJXc496FcEAAp0cQZ4VUnPit5S3WF5N3JH8lAV8NVrK5v51mUNzl3RRQTjW+kwNtZiOdmugntCfwCYZCIA))

```
declare const csvSeparator: unique symbol;

// nominal string type
type Branded<T extends string> = T & { readonly [csvSeparator]: 'CSVSeparator' }

// helper function: create branded string by applying a type assertion to it
function brand<T extends string>(s: T) {
    return s as Branded<T>
}

export type CSVSeparator = Branded<';'> | Branded<','> | Branded<' '> | Branded<'|'>
    | Branded<'.'> | Branded<'\t'>

const predefinedColumnSeparators: { name: string; character: CSVSeparator }[] = [
    { name: 'Semicolon', character: brand(';') },
    { name: 'Semicolon', character: ';' }, // error, no regular string assignable 
    ...
    { name: 'Tabulator', character: brand('\t') }
];
```

The branding is just a type declaration at compile-time, you can use it as regular `string`:

```
const regularString: string = brand(";")
```

Comment: isn't there any way to say this `const regularString: CSVSepaator = '\t';` ?

Comment: With the `CSVSeparator` type in the question, no. String prototype just isn't assignable to `{ readonly [csvSeparator]: 'CSVSeparator' }`, so it is casted like other branded primitives to make them unique in a structural typing system. But I suppose, the whole purpose was to make `"\t"` CSVSeparator distinguishable from a normal `"\t"` string? If not, you could just use answer variant 1 with simple string - here your assignment works.

Comment: My purpose is to create restiction for the value of `CSVSeparator` typed strings. This is only for developers, but this is important to avoid mistakes in the code. For example if somebody write a typo `\r` instead of `\t`. This is not a syntax error, but it will be a bug in the software. If the type restricted the values this bug will be avoidable.

Comment: If it is all about preventing a wrong string, just delete `& { readonly [csvSeparator]: 'CSVSeparator' };` from `CSVSeparator` type (first alternative in answer).

Comment: If I remove that part then `string` will be acceptable type too instead of `CSVSeparator` type. It's important to accpet only `CSVSeparator` type with only my definied values.

Comment: I am not sure, what you are meaning. Given [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=35&pln=3&pc=78#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAYQGUA1Y4MTdGaOAXjgHIBuJuAH2YBp2v2+zDoKYA6EQB0YTALAAoecggA7AM7wwWJADMAlsuAJCEVAFcAtsopUoNaKoBccAN5xl6c8Cfqo+gOYscMgAFtTIMMBQTiTklNS0UHAAvgDaALoMcCnycC5uHl7MFOa6SqgqTNxBobbhkU6s7EncOXnung3G5uboldVhEVE8TS1yua7thUzEVMjAfSED9cwrza0TBQ0ACroECzXodUNMwsmj4-kdzMblyvtLx+Jn65dTACroAEamGAn3tYMGlIRi9Jk4AEQYDDgqqLAHLcGqCCeYgwXzKPwAOQgMAAksoYtZ4tBwUk4AB6clwSJQaDyNIsIA), what do you expect it to validate further?

Comment: hmm now it's just working... it seems to be something VSCode issue was here... thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you want to use `CSVSeparator`, but you may be able to use an `enum` instead

```
enum CSVSeparator {
  Semicolon = ";",
  Comma = ",",
  Space = " ",
  Pipe = "|",
  Colon = ".",
  Tabulator = "\t"
}
```

Comment: not so good, because after this I need to use this syntax: `{name: 'Tabulator', character: CSVSeparator.Tabulator },` and I want to use this: `{name: 'Tabulator', character: '\t'},`